# How do you merge two lists into a list of sublists where each sublist is paired based on the sequence of the items in the list?

Tags: python, list, sequence, sublist

How do you merge two lists into a list of sublists where each sublist is paired based on the sequence of the items in the list?

In other words, I have three lists and I want to pair the values up in two of the lists based on a third list to form sublists. The rule to follow to do this is:

If a value in lst_b falls between a value in lst_c within lst_a, pair it up with the previous value in lst_a that is also in lst_c. For example, because 'aad' fall between two values in lst_c which are 'KEY1' and 'KEY2', pair it up with 'KEY1', since that came before 'KEY2'.

```
lst_a = ['KEY1','aad','b','KEY2','c','KEY3','d','e','f']

lst_b = ['aad','b','c','d','e','f']

lst_c = ['KEY1','KEY2','KEY3']


desired_list = [['KEY1','aad'],['KEY1','b'],['KEY2','c'],['KEY3','d'],['KEY3','e'],['KEY3','f']]
```

I don't even think this is possible in python or if it is, it would be far to complicated, so let me know if that is the case.

Comment: How do the 2 lists join to form the 3rd desired list? This question makes no sense.

Comment: sorry, i'll try to clarify

Comment: Are `lst_b` and `lst_c` necessary for your code? They seem to convey the exact same information that `lst_a` does.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't know what the Keys are without eithr lst_b or lst_c. The Keys wouldn't necessarily be obvious or apparent in the actual code, so you would have to identify them from another list

Comment: Also, OP, you should look into dictionaries as a data structure specifically designed for associating key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lst_b` and `lst_c` should not be `list`s, they should be `set`s.  All you care about is membership.

Here's how I'd write the generator:

```
def do_stuff(li, s_val, s_key):
    key = li[0]
    for x in li[1:]:
        if x in s_val:
            yield key,x
        elif x in s_key:
            key = x
```

demo:

```
list(do_stuff(lst_a,set(lst_b),set(lst_c)))
Out[24]: 
[('KEY1', 'aad'),
 ('KEY1', 'b'),
 ('KEY2', 'c'),
 ('KEY3', 'd'),
 ('KEY3', 'e'),
 ('KEY3', 'f')]
```

I assumed in the above that your first element of `lst_a` is a key, since your algorithm is undefined otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it.

```
desired_list = []
k = None
for a in lst_a:
    if a in lst_c:
        k = a
    elif a in lst_b:
        desired_list.append([k, a])
```

Comment: For each `a` in `lst_a`, this will either throw an exception since `k` is undefined or not add anything to `desired_list`

Comment: @jmu303, my answer does depend on a key being the first element, but that's assumed in the question. you could set k to None if you'd like it to fail silently.

Comment: fair enough. I also misinterpreted. Make sure to check for membership in `lst_b` too, even though in the example lists, every element of `lst_a` exists in either `lst_b` or `lst_c`